# Is this the correct way of proving that $x^n - y^n = (x-y) (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}.y + ... + x.y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I need to prove the following:

$x^n - y^n = (x-y) (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}\cdot y + ... + x\cdot y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

I'm pretty new to proofs in general, and it's hard to know when you got it right or wrong, so I'd appreciate help from a more experienced person.

I'd say we look at the second term:

$(x-y) (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} \cdot y + ... + x\cdot y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

It's the same as

$x\cdot(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}\cdot y + ... + x\cdot y^{n-2} + y^{n-1}) - y\cdot(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}\cdot y + ... + x\cdot y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

So we get:

$(x^{n-1}\cdot x + x\cdot y\cdot x^{n-2} + ... + x\cdot x\cdot y^{n-2} + x\cdot y^{n-1}) - (y\cdot x^{n-1} + y\cdot y\cdot x^{n-2} + ... + x\cdot y\cdot y^{n-2} + y\cdot y^{n-1})$

This is the same as:

$(x^n + y\cdot x^{n-1} + ... + x^2\cdot y^{n-2} + x\cdot y^{n-1}) - (y\cdot x^{n-1} +y^2\cdot x^{n-2} + ... + x\cdot y^{n-1} + y^n)$

Then, if we perform the subtraction, all terms but the first term in the left and the last term in the right cancel out, leaving only $x^n - y^n$

Thus, $x^n - y^n = x^n - y^n$.

Is this right? Is there anything else I should do?
I feel I have a tendency to just carry on with the math until one part equals the other, and I'm not sure if that is the right way to prove something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier
to use the summation notation
rather then "...".

$\begin{array}\\
(x-y)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-1-k}
&=x \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-1-k} -y \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-1-k}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k+1} y^{n-1-k} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-k}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x^{k} y^{n-1-(k-1)} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-k}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x^{k} y^{n-k} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-k}\\
&= (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{k} y^{n-k}+x^n) 
- (y^n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-k})\\
&= x^n-y^n\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I've barely started learning analysis and the summation notation still confuses me a bit. I'll certainly try to understand it better, it's definitely more 'elegant'.

Answer (score 3):

Your working is correct, and this is valid.

A note on general proof technique, though: if we want to show the truth of some equality $A = B$, we don't *begin* with the equation $A = B$ and 'look at a side', trying to manipulate it into showing $A = A$ or $B= B$ as you have done here. This smells dangerously like assuming the truth of something that you want to prove, which can lead to all sort of trouble if you're not careful.

It would be more correct (more sophisticated, more logical, more readable) to begin with *just* the expression $A$ or the expression $B$. Then we work through the steps as you have, showing for example

$$ 
B = B_1 \\
=B_2 \\
=B_3 \\
\vdots \\
= A \\
\therefore A=B
$$

See how we are *ending up* with $A = B$, rather than beginning with it? This makes it more clear that the fact $A = B$ has been derived by us.

Comment: So basically, if I were to rewrite this I would start with only the second term, and $x^n - y^n$ should only appear as the final result.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, and all of your intermediate 'Is the same as...' statements can (and should) be replaced by $=$ signs.

Comment: @ziggystarman I agree with everything stated here, but would like to note that there's no harm in stating your goal at the beginning, so long as it is clearly marked as such. This can make your proof easier to follow for the reader.

Comment: Nothing wrong with showing $A=B\iff 0=0$. This is a valid proof. But of course the $\iff$ signs should not be omitted.